# Using scrollIntoVIew in WKWebView jumps to top of page

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, webkit, wkwebview

With the code below, I'm trying to load HTML into a WKWebview, then scroll it to a particular element.

```
  let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "TestHTML", withExtension: "html")!
    myWebView.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: url)
    myWebView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('4').scrollIntoView(true);") {[weak self] (result, error) in
        print("result: \(result)")
        print (error)
    }
```

However, when I run it, the page loads, scrolls to the section, but then jumps back to the top of the page.

I have also tried setting the  `contentOffset` of the `scrollView`, resulting in the exact same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I published this question a few months ago, and while [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56779772/11704346) worked for a demo project, it wouldn't work for me in another project - it would go to the offset, then just go back to the top.

The issue seems to be that while when the code in `webView(didFinish)` runs, the web view has indeed finished loading, but the scroll view has not finished loading.

My solution is as follows:

1. Make the ViewController conform to both `WKWebViewNavigationDelegate` and `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocols

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate {
//..
}
```

2. Add two properties to the ViewController. One will be an CGPoint to store the content offset of the Scroll View, and the other will be a boolean to keep track of whether or not the Web View has finished loading, and will have a value of false.

```
var position: CGPoint?
var webViewFinished = false
```

3. in the `didFinish` delegate method, set the value of `position` to the scroll view's content offset,  and set `webViewFinished` to `true`

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        position = myWebView.scrollView.contentOffset
        webViewFinished = true
    }
```

4. In the `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate method, check if the Web View has finished loading. If it has, set the Scroll View's content offset to the value of `position`, and set `webViewFinished` to `false` (since otherwise, this code will run each time the user scrolls). Don't forget to do optional chaining on `position` as well!

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if webViewFinished {
            webViewFinished = false
            if let p = position {
                web.scrollView.setContentOffset(p, animated: false)
            }
        }
    }
```

5. Last but not least, set the Web View/Scroll View's delegates

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myWebView.navigationDelegate = self
    myWebView.scrollView.delegate = self
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should write your javascript evaluation code in webview delegate method *didFinish navigation*

```
extension WebViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("Finished navigating to url \(webView.url)")
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('4').scrollIntoView(true);") { (any, error) in
            dump(error)
            print(any)
        }
    }
}
```

and don't forget to set webview delgate

```
myWebView.navigationDelegate = self
```